# Unity Predicted Simulation with Time.timescale gets offset upto 0.3 seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2d simulation that change the timescale after each bounce so that each consecutive bounce is 1 second after the previous one. My prediction works with less than 0.01 seconds accuracy but the with time scale changing mechanism added the next bounce should be 1 second after the previous one but it happens with an offset differing from 0.01 seconds to 0.3 seconds.

Scene image:

[image: scene image]

I have 2 scripts. One that creates collier for the outer hollow circle:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(EdgeCollider2D))]
public class PreciseCircleCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]public Vector2 center;
    [SerializeField]public float radius;
    [SerializeField] public int cornerAmount;

    private EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;

    void Start()
    {
        edgeCollider = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        GenerateCollider();
    }

    void GenerateCollider()
    {
        Vector2[] edgePoints = new Vector2[cornerAmount + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= cornerAmount; i++)
        {
            float angle = i * 2 * Mathf.PI / cornerAmount;
            Vector2 edgePoint = new Vector2(
                center.x + radius * Mathf.Cos(angle),
                center.y + radius * Mathf.Sin(angle)
            );
            edgePoints[i] = edgePoint;
        }

        // Close the circle by connecting the last point to the first
        edgePoints[cornerAmount] = edgePoints[0];

        edgeCollider.points = edgePoints;
    }
}
```

Other script is ball script that handles all the mechanism of predicting next bounce and changing time scale accordingly so next bounce happens in exactly one seconds.

```
using System;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject ball;
    public GameObject outerCircle;

    private Vector2 gravity; // Gravity value from the Physics settings.
    private float circleRadius; // The radius of the circle is taken from the PreciseCircleCollider component.
    private float nextPredictedBounceTime;
    private float lastCollisionTime = 0f;
    public float desiredCollisionTime = 1f;
    public TextMeshPro timeLeftTillCollision;
    private void Awake()
    {
        ball = gameObject;
        // Assign the gravity here instead of initializing it directly in the field.
        gravity = Physics2D.gravity;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
        nextPredictedBounceTime = predictCollisionTime();
        // Get the radius from the PreciseCircleCollider component.
        circleRadius = outerCircle.GetComponent<PreciseCircleCollider>().radius;
    }

    public float predictCollisionTime()
    {
        Rigidbody2D ballRigidbody = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        // Initial position and velocity of the ball
        Vector2 currentPosition = ballRigidbody.position;
        Vector2 currentVelocity = ballRigidbody.velocity;

        // Time step for the simulation
        float timeStep = 0.01f; // Adjust time step for more accuracy
        float simulationTime = 0f; // Total time of simulation

        // Simulate the ball's trajectory
        while (simulationTime < 10f) // Use a reasonable cutoff to prevent infinite loops
        {
            // Apply gravity to velocity
            currentVelocity += gravity * ballRigidbody.gravityScale * timeStep;
            // Move ball
            currentPosition += currentVelocity * timeStep;
            // Check if the ball has reached the circle's radius
            float distanceToCircleCenter = (currentPosition - (Vector2)outerCircle.transform.position).magnitude;
            if (distanceToCircleCenter >= circleRadius)
            {
                // Ball has hit the circle's edge
                return simulationTime;
            }

            // Increment total simulation time
            simulationTime += timeStep;
        }

        // If no collision with the circle's edge is detected in the simulation time, return infinity
        return float.PositiveInfinity;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        float predictedTime = lastCollisionTime + nextPredictedBounceTime;
        float realTime = Time.unscaledTime;
        
        //debug for time difference in not time scale changed case
        //Debug.Log("REAL: " + realTime + " " + "PREDICTED: " +
        //         predictedTime + " " + "DIFF: " + (predictedTime - realTime));
        nextPredictedBounceTime = predictCollisionTime();

        lastCollisionTime = Time.unscaledTime;

        float nextPredicted = predictCollisionTime();
        float newTimeScale = (predictCollisionTime() / desiredCollisionTime);
        Debug.Log("BOUNCE  " + realTime);
        Debug.Log("Predicted: " + nextPredicted + " | desired: " + desiredCollisionTime + " | old timeScale: " + Time.timeScale + " | new timeScale: " + newTimeScale); 
        Time.timeScale = newTimeScale;
        
        //Debug.Log("Predicted bounce in " + predictCollisionTime()/Time.timeScale);
      
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        timeLeftTillCollision.text = "collision in : " + (predictCollisionTime() / Time.timeScale).ToString("F2");
    }
}
```

Console debug output:

```
BOUNCE  3.043761


Predicted: 1.539999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1 | new timeScale: 1.539999

BOUNCE  4.046417


Predicted: 0.4699998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.539999 | new timeScale: 0.4699998

BOUNCE  5.016171


Predicted: 0.8099995 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4699998 | new timeScale: 0.8099995

BOUNCE  6.01416


Predicted: 0.4699998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.8099995 | new timeScale: 0.4699998

BOUNCE  6.99934


Predicted: 1.519999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4699998 | new timeScale: 1.519999

BOUNCE  8.012904


Predicted: 1.059999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.519999 | new timeScale: 1.059999

BOUNCE  8.942515


Predicted: 0.3499999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.059999 | new timeScale: 0.3499999

BOUNCE  9.847043


Predicted: 0.21 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.3499999 | new timeScale: 0.21

BOUNCE  10.78176


Predicted: 0.2 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.21 | new timeScale: 0.2

BOUNCE  11.69582


Predicted: 0.23 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.2 | new timeScale: 0.23

BOUNCE  12.5963


Predicted: 1.359999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.23 | new timeScale: 1.359999

BOUNCE  13.5975


Predicted: 0.3 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.359999 | new timeScale: 0.3

BOUNCE  14.55297


Predicted: 0.3799999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.3 | new timeScale: 0.3799999

BOUNCE  15.50103


Predicted: 0.9599994 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.3799999 | new timeScale: 0.9599994

BOUNCE  16.49779


Predicted: 0.4999998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.9599994 | new timeScale: 0.4999998

BOUNCE  17.46734


Predicted: 0.7599996 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4999998 | new timeScale: 0.7599996

BOUNCE  18.45869


Predicted: 0.4699998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.7599996 | new timeScale: 0.4699998

BOUNCE  19.44164


Predicted: 1.469999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4699998 | new timeScale: 1.469999

BOUNCE  20.44103


Predicted: 0.28 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.469999 | new timeScale: 0.28

BOUNCE  21.36184


Predicted: 0.31 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.28 | new timeScale: 0.31

BOUNCE  22.30084


Predicted: 1.319999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.31 | new timeScale: 1.319999

BOUNCE  23.31648


Predicted: 0.5199998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.319999 | new timeScale: 0.5199998

BOUNCE  24.2693


Predicted: 0.7099996 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.5199998 | new timeScale: 0.7099996

BOUNCE  25.26228


Predicted: 0.5399998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.7099996 | new timeScale: 0.5399998

BOUNCE  26.24833


Predicted: 0.7299996 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.5399998 | new timeScale: 0.7299996

BOUNCE  27.23529


Predicted: 0.4899998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.7299996 | new timeScale: 0.4899998

BOUNCE  28.22517


Predicted: 1.569999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4899998 | new timeScale: 1.569999

BOUNCE  29.22903


Predicted: 0.4599998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.569999 | new timeScale: 0.4599998

BOUNCE  30.18347


Predicted: 0.7899995 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4599998 | new timeScale: 0.7899995

BOUNCE  31.18207


Predicted: 0.4399998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.7899995 | new timeScale: 0.4399998

BOUNCE  32.17106


Predicted: 1.579999 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.4399998 | new timeScale: 1.579999

BOUNCE  33.17672


Predicted: 0.5099998 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 1.579999 | new timeScale: 0.5099998

BOUNCE  34.13616


Predicted: 0.6799996 | desired: 1 | old timeScale: 0.5099998 | new timeScale: 0.6799996
```

Comment: What do you mean by offset? BTW the default timestep of Unity is 0.02s.

Comment: I mean consecutive bounces are 1 + some offset apart from each other(3.043761, 4.046417,  5.016171 and continues.) when they are supposed to be exactly 1 second apart from each other. Also i changed the fixed timestep to 0.0015 in  project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Something you need to consider:

1. Your prediction missed 1 frame, it should be:

   ```
   // Increment total simulation time
   simulationTime += timeStep;

   if (distanceToCircleCenter >= circleRadius)
   {
       // Ball has hit the circle's edge
       return simulationTime;
   }
   ```

   It is obvious that Unity also needs the ball to cross the collider before calculating the rebound, so the time spent in this frame needs to be added.
2. The entire collision process includes three stages: `Enter`, `Stay`, and `Exit`, and the time you printed is the time between the two `Enter` events. The actual collision process is quite complex, and if you observe the velocity of the ball in the three stages, they are different. And in your prediction, the velocity remains constant. So in fact, what you predicted should be the time between the previous `Exit` event and this `Enter` event.
3. The ball is not a point, so it will have a size, which may result in actual collisions occurring several frames earlier than predicted. Although reducing the radius can avoid this situation to the furthest possible, it may be better to include the radius in the prediction.
4. Strange `Time.unscaledDeltaTime`.

   If you print the value of `Time.unscaledDeltaTime`, you will find that when you modify the `timeScale`, in next frame, the value of `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` does not immediately change to the corresponding value after the timeScale is modified. It seems that Unity will try to add an interpolation, which leads to a gap between your predicted time and the actual time returned by `Time.unscaledTime`.

   I used a customized time for better result

   ```
   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       realUnscaledTime += Time.deltaTime / Time.timeScale;
   }
   ```
5. If the timestep used in your prediction method is different from the actual `fixedDeltaTime`, there will be slight differences in the calculated results.